# PWA ignores os orientation lock on android

Tags: progressive-web-apps

My pwa (https://www.nextpicnic.org) ignores the os orientation lock on android phones. The pwa is changing its orientation when the lock is enabled on os level.

Don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Solved by removing "orientation": "any" from manifest.